# Raspberry Pie 3 Why do I get an error when installing wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

[image]
I am trying to install wxpython on raspberry pi3.

```
raspbian2.4.1 / Python 3.4 pip3 is version 9.0.1.
Firmware, Updates, Upgrades
Apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
Apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
Apt-get install gstreamer1.0 *
Apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
Apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

If you install `pip3 install wxpython` after this pre-installation, it will not continue to install as shown in the picture. What's wrong?
Cpu and ram usage soar to 100%.

---- 2017-07-17 edit ----

Thank you all for your reply. I've tried a lot of the answers but I still can not install it.

I did not have any problems with Ubuntu 16.04, but I do not know why Raspberry Pie 3 is doing this in Razbian. Is this because Python 3 is not fully supported by RazBian?

I unzipped tar.gz and installed setup.py inside with the following command. I think the error is on the webkit gateways.

```
Sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
Sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-dev
```

I have also tried installing Raspberry Pie 3 python3, wxpython phoenix version I am doing wrong how to install?

`pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3 $ python3 setup.py install --user`

```
        running install
        running build
        WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
        generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly
        to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use
        --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
        message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.

        "/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build
        Will build using: "/usr/bin/python3"
        3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
        [GCC 4.9.1]
        Python's architecture is 32bit
        cfg.VERSION: 4.0.0a3

        Running command: build
        Running command: build_wx
        wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode', '--no_config']
        Configure options: ['--enable-unicode', '--with-opengl', '--enable-sound', '--enable-graphics_ctx', '--enable-mediactrl', '--enable-display', '--enable-geometry', '--enable-debug_flag', '--enable-optimise', '--disable-debugreport', '--enable-uiactionsim', '--with-sdl']
        /usr/bin/make
        make --jobs=4
        (if test -f utils/wxrc/Makefile ; then cd utils/wxrc && make all ; fi)
        make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/utils/wxrc'
        make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.     

    ........

    4.0.0a3/ext/wxWidgets/locale'
        Finished command: build_wx (0m3.803s)
        Running command: build_py
        Checking for /home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/bin/waf-1.7.15-p1...
        "/usr/bin/python3" /home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/bin/waf-1.7.15-p1 --wx_config=/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/wx-config --python="/usr/bin/python3" --out=build/waf/3.4 configure build
        Setting top to                           : /home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3
        Setting out to                           : /home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4
        Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
        Checking for 'g++' (c++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++
        Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python3
        Checking for python version              : (3, 4, 2, 'final', 0)
        Checking for library python3.4 in LIBDIR : not found
        Checking for library python3.4 in python_LIBPL : yes
        Checking for program /usr/bin/python3-config,python3.4-config,python-config-3.4,python3.4m-config : /usr/bin/python3-config
        Checking for header Python.h                                                                      : yes

......

        Waf: Leaving directory `/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4'
        Build failed
         -> task in '_html2' failed (exit status 1):
                {task 1943459824: cxx sip_html2wxWebViewEvent.cpp -> sip_html2wxWebViewEvent.cpp.17.o}
        ['/usr/bin/g++', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-pthread', '-UNDEBUG', '-g', '-pthread', '-fwrapv', '-fstack-protector-strong', '-flto', '-fuse-linker-plugin', '-ffat-lto-objects', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/ext/wxWidgets/include', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/src', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/src', '-I/usr/include/python3.4m', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DHAVE_PYTHON_H=1', '-DHAVE_WX=1', '-DHAVE_WXADV=1', '-DHAVE_WXSTC=1', '-DHAVE_WXHTML=1', '-DHAVE_WXGL=1', '-DHAVE_WXWEBVIEW=1', '-DHAVE_WXXML=1', '-DHAVE_WXXRC=1', '-DHAVE_WXRICHTEXT=1', '-DHAVE_WXMEDIA=1', '-DHAVE_WXRIBBON=1', '-DHAVE_WXPROPGRID=1', '-DHAVE_WXAUI=1', '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64', '-DWXUSINGDLL', '-D__WXGTK__', '../../../sip/cpp/sip_html2wxWebViewEvent.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'sip/cpp/sip_html2wxWebViewEvent.cpp.17.o']
         -> task in '_html2' failed (exit status 1):
                {task 1943459632: cxx sip_html2cmodule.cpp -> sip_html2cmodule.cpp.17.o}
        ['/usr/bin/g++', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-pthread', '-UNDEBUG', '-g', '-pthread', '-fwrapv', '-fstack-protector-strong', '-flto', '-fuse-linker-plugin', '-ffat-lto-objects', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/ext/wxWidgets/include', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/src', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/src', '-I/usr/include/python3.4m', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DHAVE_PYTHON_H=1', '-DHAVE_WX=1', '-DHAVE_WXADV=1', '-DHAVE_WXSTC=1', '-DHAVE_WXHTML=1', '-DHAVE_WXGL=1', '-DHAVE_WXWEBVIEW=1', '-DHAVE_WXXML=1', '-DHAVE_WXXRC=1', '-DHAVE_WXRICHTEXT=1', '-DHAVE_WXMEDIA=1', '-DHAVE_WXRIBBON=1', '-DHAVE_WXPROPGRID=1', '-DHAVE_WXAUI=1', '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64', '-DWXUSINGDLL', '-D__WXGTK__', '../../../sip/cpp/sip_html2cmodule.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'sip/cpp/sip_html2cmodule.cpp.17.o']
         -> task in '_html2' failed (exit status 1):
                {task 1943459760: cxx sip_html2wxWebViewArchiveHandler.cpp -> sip_html2wxWebViewArchiveHandler.cpp.17.o}
        ['/usr/bin/g++', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-pthread', '-UNDEBUG', '-g', '-pthread', '-fwrapv', '-fstack-protector-strong', '-flto', '-fuse-linker-plugin', '-ffat-lto-objects', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/ext/wxWidgets/include', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/src', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/src', '-I/usr/include/python3.4m', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DHAVE_PYTHON_H=1', '-DHAVE_WX=1', '-DHAVE_WXADV=1', '-DHAVE_WXSTC=1', '-DHAVE_WXHTML=1', '-DHAVE_WXGL=1', '-DHAVE_WXWEBVIEW=1', '-DHAVE_WXXML=1', '-DHAVE_WXXRC=1', '-DHAVE_WXRICHTEXT=1', '-DHAVE_WXMEDIA=1', '-DHAVE_WXRIBBON=1', '-DHAVE_WXPROPGRID=1', '-DHAVE_WXAUI=1', '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64', '-DWXUSINGDLL', '-D__WXGTK__', '../../../sip/cpp/sip_html2wxWebViewArchiveHandler.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'sip/cpp/sip_html2wxWebViewArchiveHandler.cpp.17.o']
         -> task in '_html2' failed (exit status 1):
                {task 1943459696: cxx sip_html2wxWebView.cpp -> sip_html2wxWebView.cpp.17.o}
        ['/usr/bin/g++', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-pthread', '-UNDEBUG', '-g', '-pthread', '-fwrapv', '-fstack-protector-strong', '-flto', '-fuse-linker-plugin', '-ffat-lto-objects', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/ext/wxWidgets/include', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/sip/siplib', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/waf/3.4/src', '-I/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/src', '-I/usr/include/python3.4m', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages"', '-DHAVE_PYTHON_H=1', '-DHAVE_WX=1', '-DHAVE_WXADV=1', '-DHAVE_WXSTC=1', '-DHAVE_WXHTML=1', '-DHAVE_WXGL=1', '-DHAVE_WXWEBVIEW=1', '-DHAVE_WXXML=1', '-DHAVE_WXXRC=1', '-DHAVE_WXRICHTEXT=1', '-DHAVE_WXMEDIA=1', '-DHAVE_WXRIBBON=1', '-DHAVE_WXPROPGRID=1', '-DHAVE_WXAUI=1', '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64', '-DWXUSINGDLL', '-D__WXGTK__', '../../../sip/cpp/sip_html2wxWebView.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'sip/cpp/sip_html2wxWebView.cpp.17.o']
        Command '"/usr/bin/python3" /home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/bin/waf-1.7.15-p1 --wx_config=/home/pi/Downloads/wxPython-4.0.0a3/build/wxbld/wx-config --python="/usr/bin/python3" --out=build/waf/3.4 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
        Finished command: build_py (0m18.606s)
        Finished command: build (0m22.411s)
        Command '"/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
```

---

In raspbian, add software-wxpython search. After installing all wxwidgets, the wxpython module is installed.
I checked wxpython (4.0.0a3) with pip3 list and imported it in python3.

I do not know what wxwidgets installed, but thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: Are you using `sudo`?

Comment: yes `sudo` used

Comment: Can you see the build output prior to what is shown above? The error shown doesn't make sense, unless the cmdproc.h file has been trashed, which seems unlikely. There may be other errors before that are confusing things at the point shown above. If not then next step would be to fetch the source tarball and try running a build yourself without pip. See the README.rst in the source tree.

Comment: At the original poster: the last two paragraphs seem to suggest you finally managed to install wxPython Phoenix. If so, would you mind to post an answer to your question outlining the precise steps (your last two sentences sound very unclear to me).